# word add-in not updating ribbon when side panel is closed

Tags: c#, vsto

Hey I am having an issue with my word add-in.

Basically I have a ribbon and a side panel. When I click show panel on my ribbon it displays my panel and when I click hide it now hides the panel.

Now the issue I am having is when I click the 'x' button on the top right of the add-in the show/hide button is not changing text.

Can anyone advise me on how to add an event listener or something along those lines for the  side panel closing to change the text?

[image]

[image]

```
namespace examplele_word
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainContainerPanel.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainContainerPanel : UserControl
  {
      private WordDocInstanceController _controller;
      public WordDocInstanceController controller {
          get {
              return this._controller;
          }
          set {
              this._controller = value;
              this.itemDetailsPanel.controller = value;
              this.searchItemsPanel.controller = value;
              this.loginPanel.controller = value;
          }
      }

      public MainContainerPanel()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      public void showLoginPanel()
      {
          itemDetailsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
          searchItemsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
          loginPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      }
      public void showSearchItemsPanel()
      {
          loginPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
          itemDetailsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
          searchItemsPanel.resetPanel();
          searchItemsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      }
      public void showItemDetailsPanel (ItemDTO item)
      {
          itemDetailsPanel.displayNewItem(item);
          loginPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
          searchItemsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
          itemDetailsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      }


    }
}
```

Comment: can you include your current code in the question?

Comment: Do I need to? Basically I want to know how to override the on close event of the side panel. I'm not sure how my current code would help that

Comment: The code behind your views probably has the quickest path to the answer...

Comment: Added in the code behind for the main container. I am trying to add an on close event here

Comment: your 'x' button should already have a function tied to it? Maybe in the login controller?

Comment: I don't think so..... It looks like it's a default word setting

Comment: Hmmm at this point I'd recommend attaching the debugger and stepping through line by line to see exactly what runs after you click the 'x' button

Comment: Hmmm cool.... I'll keep looking... The problem I'm having is that I can't find anything that is being hit by the 'x' button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the `VisibleChanged` event to determine when the end user closes the custom task pane. However please note that Office applications prevent you from changing some custom task pane properties in the `VisibleChanged` event handler, including `Width`, `Height`, `Visible`, and `DockPosition`. If you try to modify these properties, you'll receive a `COMException`.

> the show/hide button is not changing text

It is your responsibility to change the text on the ribbon depending on the task pane states. The Ribbon UI and custom task panes are not connected to each other.

To get the job done you need to use call the [IRibbonUI.Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate.aspx) or [IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method which allows to invalidate the cached values for one or all of the controls of the Ribbon user interface.

In the ribbon callbacks you need to return appropriate values depending on the task panel state.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)